# Java Interface for Multimedia Keys

Tags: java, user-interface, keyboard, swt, keylistener

Anyone has experiences about interfacing with multimedia [or Fn Function] keys in Java?

There seems to be an incomplete discussion regarding multimedia buttons in Java [here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5397084&start=0&tstart=0). There is also a library, [JIntelliType](http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/index.html), which can be used to register global hotkeys in Windows, but only works for registering globally, not media keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incorrect.  I am the author of JIntellitype and you can call registerIntellitypeListener in this example and it registers for the Multimedia keys of Windows like Play Pause Stop etc.

http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/quick-start.html