# Media/fn keys in java

Tags: java, swing, events, key

I am currently developing a media application in java using the gstreamer bindings for java. All is going well except for one small issue regarding the keyboard, specifically the media keys (e.g. play/pause, back, next).

I have Actions that work fine as buttons/menu items for these functions, and was hoping to allow the use of the keys that are on some keyboards (often on laptops). However, I could not find andthing in java.awt.event.KeyEvent to represent these keys. I tried running the snippet of code below, and it worked fine for most keys, including f1-12, but did not respond to 'fn' nor to the media keys while 'fn' was held.

Does anyone know how to get these keys working?

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Key extends JFrame{

    public Key(){

        JTextField f = new JTextField(50);
        f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                System.out.printf("%s : %d \n", e.getKeyChar(), e.getKeyCode());
            }
        });
        setContentPane(f);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Key();  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `e.getKeyChar()` and `e.getKeyCode()` keys don't return anything when you press those keys, I'm not aware of any other way to get those events via the standard Java library, other than [using JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to get the codes at a lower level.

You seem to be on the right track, trying to get the key codes when a key is pressed, which is how you would discover key codes when you don't know what the proper constant is in Java.

Other than that, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689948/java-interface-for-multimedia-keys) seems to offer some possibilities (though I'm not sure if this only works with Microsoft IntelliType devices, or if it will work cross-platform). When I use a Microsoft IntelliType keyboard on my Mac, for example, the media keys seem to work just fine.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say something like that :/ thought I'd ask anyway

Comment: Hm, updated my answer. You might be able to use the JIntelliType thing.