# How to handle blue function key in Java?

Tags: java, android, key

I'm trying to write a client / server remote control application, server side in Java and client side in Android (kind of Java).

Server program will receive commands from client, such as "PLAY", "STOP" and so on. These commands are processed by the server and using an extension Java's Robot class key strokes are sent to the machine were the server is running.

The thing is that I'd like to use that magical key that is included in new keyboards, the "blue function" key. With this blue function key pressed you can invoke multimedia command wush as mute, play, pause...

The problem is that Java (as far as I know) is not able to recognize this key being pressed. Have you ever come across this issue before?

Comment: Is the key pressed standalone even submitted to the OS at all?

Comment: Isn't this key a “shift” type key… ? I've never actually seen one of these, up close, but doesn't it alter the keypress events that you receive, just as “shift” or “alt/fn” keys do on Android?

Comment: Hi all,Thank you for you responses. The key function that I'm talking about could be found on this image http://www.theunwired.net/media/column/thinkoutside_bluetooth/keyboard/DSCN2749.JPG. It is submitted to every OS that I've tried so far (Window & Linux).

Comment: I tthink that this question has been asked before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648896/media-fn-keys-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I also think that this question is a duplicated of [Media/fn keys in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7648896/1290442) ;P.